# Why do my composes overlap eachother and how can I stop this? (Jetpack Compose App in Android Studio)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have this Jetpack Compose App and I have 2 main composes, each having their own elements and one overlaps another. Can someone help me putting them in order from top to down?

-> mainGame compose overlaps the header compose[enter image description here]
[[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIyGM.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75qLS.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jefvn.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8JgM.png)(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bx2vV.png)

I tried to do a random generator app and the higher number wins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you wish to have your `header` on top with your `mainGame` below it.

You seem to be placing your elements in your preview directly into `mainContent`. Try placing a `Column` first (with its size set to max) and then placing your content inside of it. This will automatically stack them vertically.

In practice:

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview(){
    BarbutAppTheme{
        mainContent{
            Column(modifier = Modifer.fillMaxSize()){
                header()
                mainGame()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you wish them otherwise, you can check [this introduction](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/basics) from Android Developers.